# How to translate difference between "don't have to" and "must not"?

Tags: english-to-german, difference

In English, these two are different concepts:

> You don't have to read the book.
>
> You must not read the book.

But in German, I believe the same sentence would work for either one.

> Du musst das Buch nicht lesen.

Reading this sentence in isolation, I would suppose it meant "You don't have to read the book." Is there a way to force an interpretation of "You must not read the book."? Would you have to use dürfen for that? Maybe like:

> Du darfst das Buch nicht lesen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, the pairs are:

- nicht müssen = do not have to
- nicht dürfen = must not

Maybe you can remember this more easily by understanding that with *müssen* and *dürfen*, *nicht* applies to a different part of the statement than *not* for *must*:

- In German, *nicht* negates the modal verb.
- In English, *not* negates the action subject to the modal verb.

Comment: it may be easier to think of 'not being allowed [to]' instead of 'must not' when it comes to translating. This is just an advice for Beginners you will get used to.

Answer (score 3):

German and English are closely related languages, but their negation logic for auxiliary verbs works differently, although cognates work almost the same in positive commands.

### Commands

- EN: `S V INF O`
  DE: `S V O INF`

> 1. - *You **[do] have to** read the book.*
>        ⇔ *Du **hast** das Buch **zu** lesen.*
>        ≈ *Du **musst/sollst** das Buch lesen.*
> 2. - *You **must** read the book.*
>        ⇔ *Du **musst** das Buch lesen.*

### Negation

> 1. - *You **have to not** read the book.* `S V ¬INF O`
>        ⇔ *Du **hast** das Buch **nicht zu** lesen.* `S V O ¬INF`
>    - *You ?**have not to** read the book.*
>        ⇔ *Du ?**hast nicht** das Buch **zu** lesen.*
>    - *You **do not have to** read the book.* `S ¬V INF O`
>        ↮ *Du **hast** das Buch **nicht zu** lesen.* `S V O ¬INF`
>        ≈ *Du **darfst** das Buch **nicht** lesen.* `S V O ¬INF`
>        ⇔ *You **may not** read the book.* `S V ¬INF O`
>        = *You **may not** read the book.* `S ¬V INF O` ≠ *You ?**do not may** read the book.*
>        ⇔ *Du **darfst nicht** das Buch lesen.* `S ¬V O INF`
>    - *You **do not have to** read the book.* `S ¬V INF O`
>        ↔ *Du **brauchst** das Buch **nicht [zu]** lesen.* `S V O ¬INF`
>        ⇔ *You **need not** read the book.* `S V ¬INF O`
>        ≈ *You **do not need to** read the book.* `S ¬V INF O`
>        ⇔ *Du ?**brauchst nicht** das Buch **[zu]** lesen.* `S ¬V O INF`
> 2. - *You **must not** read the book.* `S ¬V INF O` ≠ *You ?**do not must** read the book.*
>        ⇏ *Du ?**musst nicht** das Buch lesen.* `S ¬V O INF`
>        ≈ *Du **musst** nicht das Buch lesen.* `S V ¬O INF`
>    - *You **must not** read the book.* `S V ¬INF O`
>        ↮ *Du **musst** das Buch **nicht** lesen.* `S V O ¬INF`
>        ≈ *Du **brauchst** das Buch **nicht [zu]** lesen.* `S V O ¬INF`
>        ↔ *You **do not need to** read the book* `S ¬V INF O`
>    - *You **must not** read the book.* `S V ¬INF O` ≈ `S ¬V INF O`
>        ↔ *Du **darfst/sollst** das Buch **nicht** lesen.* `S V O ¬INF`

Comment: This is all true but the context is important here as always. E.g: If the boss in an office tells the cleaning lady "Sie müssen mein Bürozimmer heute nicht putzen" or "Sie brauchen meinen Schreibtisch nicht zu aufräumen" this really means that she shouldn't do this. Surely it would be wrong if she did

Comment: Could you explain what the squiggly symbols indicate?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you write "must not" would become "darfst nicht". Contrary to "must" and "may", both "müssen" and "dürfen" have proper infinitives and can be used normally in questions and negations.