# "Du musst es nicht tun" Zweideutigkeit?

Tags: grammar-identification

Nehmen wir folgendes Beispiel:

> "Morgen gehe ich zu... und mache ..."
> - "Du musst es nicht tun"

Hat der zweite Satz die Bedeutung des englischen:

> You must not do it.

oder:

> You don't have to do it.

Ähnlich betrifft meine Frage das verneinte "dürfen" ("Du darfst es nicht tun").

Bezieht sich die Veneinung auf das "musst"/"darfst", das "tun" oder ist es ohne Kontext unklar?

Comment: Es muss heissen _"You don't have to do it."_. _"You must not do it."_ heisst auf Deutsch: _"Du **darfst** es **nich**t tun"_. Da aber Fragen zur Übersetzung in andere Sprachen _off-topic_ auf dieser Seite sind, schreibe ich das nicht als Antwort.

Comment: Vier close votes, alle mit demselben unangemessenen Grund. Es geht nicht um eine Übersetzung. Englisch wird hier nur benutzt, um über die Bedeutung des Satzes zu sprechen. Ein passender Schließungsgrund wäre Duplikat gewesen: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34912/how-to-translate-difference-between-dont-have-to-and-must-not.

Comment: @David Vogt Genau. Find' ich merkwürdig, dass es manchen Menschen nicht klar war. Ich habe eine Übersetzung benutzt weil die Frage so einfach kürzer ist, als sie nur mit Deutsch darzustellen.

Comment: @sermonionx _"Was würde der zweite Satz auf English heißen:"_ fragt doch eindeutig nach einer Übersetzung, oder habe ich etwas verpasst?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Es war im Sinne von: "Hat der zweite Satz die Bedeutung des englischen ... oder ...?". Die Bedeutungen der englischen Sätze sind mir klar, deswegen habe ich sie in die Frage einbezogen.

Comment: @sermonionx Dann schreib' das doch bitte auch so, und nicht so missverständlich.

Comment: @DavidVogt Duplikat ist kein Schließungsgrund, da die verlinkte Frage auf Englisch gestellt ist, und diese hier auf Deutsch. Daher votiere ich dafür, die Frage wieder zu öffnen.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Das mit der Sprache mache ich immer falsch. Ich wollte eigentlich darauf hinweisen, daß man nachdenken sollte, bevor man fürs Schließen votiert.

Comment: You are free to not do it. Darfen is the verb for можна - to be allowed.

Comment: @mathreadler Du bist davon ausgegangen, dass ich Russisch spreche? :)

Comment: @sermonionx Nö, nicht eigentlich. Ich wollte meistens nur sagen das solche Wörter gibt es auch in andere Sprache, aber nicht Englisch. Russisch war nur die erste die ich dachte über. In Schwedisch kann man auch sagen "att få (lov)". "Att inte få lov", etw. nicht zu dürfen. Yandex ist auch sehr viel besser als Google, diese Dinge zu übersetzen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Masatwwos Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/59107/5999) ist zwar inhaltlich bereits zutreffend und vollständig, ich würde die Frage aber dennoch gerne unter spezieller Berücksichtigung des abschließenden Satzes aus der Frage beantworten:

> Bezieht sich die Veneinung auf das "musst"/"darfst", das "tun" oder ist es ohne Kontext unklar?

Genau das ist nämlich der entscheidende Unterschied zwischen den englischen und deutschen Begriffen:

Im Englischen bezieht sich die Verneinung in der Tat auf "tun"; mit so etwas wie mathematischer Klammerschreibweise ausgedrückt also:

> You must (not do it).

In anderen Worten: Der Angesprochene ist verpflichtet, "es **nicht** zu tun".

Im Deutschen hingegeben bezieht sich die Verneinung auf "müssen" (und es ist auch nicht unklar ohne Kontext, sondern immer so):

> Du (musst [es] nicht) tun.

In anderen Worten: Der Angesprochene ist **nicht** verpflichtet, "es zu tun".

Comment: Man könnte noch ergänzen, dass es für "nicht tun" den Begriff "unterlassen" gibt. Das Gegenteil vom Zwang etwas zu tun kann also entweder die Freiheit sein, etwas zu tun, oder der Zwang, etwas zu unterlassen.

Answer (score 7):

Das ist ein falscher Freund (false friend)

"**Must not**" ist im Deutschen "**nicht dürfen**"

"**need not**" ist "**nicht müssen**"

Das kann sehr viel Verwirrung stiften.

Answer (score 1):

"Du musst es nicht tun" ist praktisch bedeutungsgleich mit "Du brauchst es nicht zu tun". Es scheint allerdings, dass "nicht brauchen" aus der Mode gekommen ist. Immerhin macht die "nicht-brauchen-Variante" klar, dass die korrekte Übersetzung ins Englische "you need not do it" lautet.